# How to expand C++ macro in Android Studio?

Tags: android, c++, android-studio, android-ndk, macros

I am writing C++ code in Android Studio and using macros.
For example:

```
#define USE_KEY(param) "KEY_" #param, param
void Keys::saveToPreferences() { 
    setString(USE_KEY(token));
}
```

I want to see the expansion of the macro in the IDE to verify it is working as I expect (same as is available in Eclipse in the explore macro expansion functionality).

So for this example the macro expansion would be:

```
setString("KEY_" "token", token);
```

Is this feature available in Android Studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer. This feature is called macro replacement and not expansion in Android Studio. It is available by default when you hover over a macro with the mouse (you need to expand the box to see it like this):

[image: Screen shot from Android Studio]